# "Оценка, а тем более самооценка обучающегося..." Вторая запятая нужна?

Tags: пунктуация

> Оценка, а тем более самооценка обучающегося, не просто может, она
> должна быть постоянной, своевременной, систематической.

1. Нужна ли запятая после "а тем более самооценка"? Если нужна, то уже после "обучающегося" ставить запятую не нужно?
   Или здесь оба варианта возможны (то есть или запятая только перед "обучающегося", или запятая только после "обучающегося")?
2. Перед "она", может, лучше поставить тире?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Оценка, а тем более самооценка** обучающегося не просто может — она должна быть постоянной, своевременной, систематической.*

1. В этом предложении используется **составной союз А ТЕМ БОЛЕЕ,** состоящий из союза и наречия (в качестве конкретизатора значения). Его синтаксическая роль может быть различной, что и определяет постановку знаков. Если он обозначает сочинительную связь, то **обособления нет**. В то же время он может относиться к уточняющим членам и **обособляться** вместе с ними.
2. Здесь мы не можем обособить оборот, так как слово "обучающегося" относится с обоим словам (оценка и самооценка),  **связь сочинительная**. Смысл такой: *Оценка и (тем более) самооценка обучающегося...*

Также можно поставить интонационное **тире** вместо запятой, чтобы подчеркнуть противопоставление.

3. В реальных текстах  (из Нацкорпуса) мы видим **оба варианта оформления** (с обособлением и без обособления):

Зимнего дворца, **а тем более** Бастилии поблизости не оказалось, поэтому хмельной инсургент открыл беспощадный огонь по случайному автомобилю. [Ночной ковбой с улицы Робеспьера // «Криминальная хроника», 2003.06.24]

Предугадать, как развернутся события в течение ближайших месяцев, **а тем более лет**, не мог никто… [Юрий Гуллер. Русский бунт, демократический, но беспощадный // «Вечерняя Москва», 2002.03.14]

Среди сослуживцев, **а тем более сверстниц**, она не знала никого, кто обладал бы подобным сокровищем. [Людмила Улицкая. Казус Кукоцкого [Путешествие в седьмую сторону света] // «Новый Мир», 2000]

Переписывать, **а тем более** уносить домой не разрешалось. [И. Н. Вирабов. Андрей Вознесенский (2015)]